# Custom Fields for Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

For my custom post type I've created custom fields called price.
Using this custom post field and `post_title` i would like to generate separate page where i will use `foreach` condition to generate table with the `post_title`, `post_link` and price.

Is there any chance to do it ?

Comment: what do you mean by `generate separate page` also what have you tried so far and where do you have issues?

Comment: create separate "page" where i will use wordpress template which allow me to get specific information from "custom_post_fields" called price.
In this temple i will use foreach statement which will generate for me price list.